# cocos2d audio file issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am using a CDLongAudioSource to play my music in my cocos2d game. But the issue is my game  crashes some time when my audio file only loads but not play because I go back from my scene to other then if I come again in my scene where audio file need to  play app crash.

Function to play file:

```
-(void)playMyEffect:(NSString*)audioFile{
    CDLongAudioSource*currentSound = [[CDAudioManager sharedManager] audioSourceForChannel:kASC_Right];
    //[currentSound load:@""];
    NSLog(@" file path to play %@",audioFile);
    [currentSound load:audioFile];
    currentSound.delegate = self;
    currentSound.backgroundMusic = NO;
    self.isSpeechComplete = NO;
    [currentSound play];
}
```

[image: Error: screen shot]

Comment: What is the crash report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you stop the player, and remove memory reference before navigating to other scene. I think this should work.